# How to fix attribute error when trying to get rid of scientific notation? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am trying to have the actual values just written instead of the scientific notation that it currently has. Here is my code that I currently have:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
pd.Series(y_vals, index=x_vals).nlargest(10).plot.bar(color ='maroon', width = 0.4)
plt.xlabel("Company")
plt.xticks(rotation = 360)
plt.ylabel("Value of Purchases")
plt.title("Top Insider Purchases of the Year")


#plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.show()
```

When I use the code that I commented out, I get this error- AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter

I tried to change it to scalar format too but it was saying it is undefined. Thanks in advance

Comment: _I tried to change it to scalar format too but it was saying it is undefined_ Show us what you tried.  Otherwise we can only guess at the real problem.

Comment: formatter = ScalarFormatter()
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, formatter=formatter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you are trying to format `string` labels with a number formatter. That cannot work. The trick is to limit the formatting to the axis that actually has numbers (`axis='y'`).

The second issue is that `offset` refers to the offset to `0` that is not needed, since is similar to all data. What you want is `style='plain'`. See [`ticklabel_format` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

---

I couldn't recreate the `pd.Series` call in my setup, so I use a plain `matplotlib.bar` call with some sample data. The output should be similar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

companies = ['AKUS', 'UHAL', 'HHC', 'ASPN']
purchases = [3.6e8, 2.45e8, 1.5e8, 1.1e8]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.bar(companies, purchases)
plt.xlabel("Company")
plt.ylabel("Value of Purchases")
plt.title("Top Insider Purchases of the Year")
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')

plt.show()
```

[image: Outcome]

---

Final remark: Why do you rotate by 360°? 360° = 0°, so the rotation is superflous and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. And for some reason the label started sideways so I had 90 but then the 90 became sideways so I just put 360 to see and I haven't removed it